# If/Else alternative

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {

    if (c1 == '{' || c1 == '}') {
        return (c2 == '{' || c2 == '}');
    } else if (c1 == '(' || c1 == ')') {
        return (c2 == '(' || c2 == ')');
    } else if (c1 == '[' || c1 == ']') {
        return (c2 == '[' || c2 == ']');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the above code in my program and I was wondering if there is a better way to implement this method without using a lot of if/else statements.

Comment: @Tom my bad, didn't see the variable difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Pairs of Characters in an Array of Char Array(s)

You could extract your symbol pairs (open and close) into a `char[][]`, and then loop through that array to test for matches. Something like,

```
static final char[][] pairs = { { '{', '}' }, { '(', ')' }, { '[', ']' } };

public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {
    for (char[] pair : pairs) {
        if (c1 == pair[0] || c1 == pair[1]) {
            return c2 == pair[0] || c2 == pair[1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Pairs of Characters in an Array of String(s)

**Alternatively**, it *may* be easier to read<sup>**1**</sup> if we implement that with `String`(s) and [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)<sup>**2**</sup>. Something like,

```
public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {
    String[] pairs = { "{}", "()", "[]" };
    for (String pair : pairs) {
        if (pair.indexOf(c1) != -1) {
            return pair.indexOf(c2) != -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>And that's never a *bad thing*.</sub></sup>
<sup>**2**<sub>The linked Javadoc says, in part, *In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then `-1` is returned.*</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3):

[Elliott's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38947847/535871) is going to be much better than mine, but I thought I'd have some fun.

```
private static final Map<Character, Set<Character>> pairMap;

public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {
    Set<Character> s = pairMap.get(c1);
    return s != null && s.contains(c2);
}

static {
    pairMap = new HashMap<>();
    register(makeSet('{', '}'));
    register(makeSet('(', ')'));
    register(makeSet('[', ']'));
}

private static Set<Character> makeSet(char... chars) {
    Set<Character> s = new HashSet<>(chars.length, 1.0f);
    for (char c : chars) {
        s.add(c);
    }
    return s;
}

private static void register(Set<Character> s) {
    for (Character c : s) {
        pairMap.put(c, s);
    }
}
```

The memory requirements for this solution are gross. The only thing it has to recommend it is that it will scale better in terms of execution time if you need to handle a very large number of character equivalence classes instead of the three pairs. Plus it can be generalized to handle other types besides `char` (or, to be accurate, `Character`).

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String PAIRS = "{}()[]";
public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {
    int indexOfC1 = PAIRS.indexOf(c1);
    int indexOfC2 = PAIRS.indexOf(c2);
    return indexOfC1 >= 0 && indexOfC2 >= 0 && (indexOfC1 / 2 == indexOfC2 / 2);   
}
```

A bit on the tricky side, perhaps...

Comment: You also have to test indexOfC2 >= 0, because -1 / 2 is 0.

Comment: Or even `(PAIRS.indexOf(c1) ^ PAIRS.indexOf(c2) & -2) == 0` for the one-liner.

Comment: Oh, except my suggestion has the same bug as Christian pointed out, with not considering -1.

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse fixed.  I keep forgetting that these stupid C-style definitions of `/` and `%` don't have the nice mathematical properties they ought to have.

Comment: @DavidWallace Which has precedence, `^` or `&`?  I don't feel like looking it up right now.

Comment: @DavidWallace And you have to use parentheses, because the & operator has a higher precedence than ^ and &. == has higher precedence than ^ and &,
How about: `((PAIRS.indexOf(c1) & 15 ^ PAIRS.indexOf(c2)) & -2) == 0`

Comment: Yeah, OK, so my one-liner was badly broken.  Yes, `&` has precedence over `^` which means I look foolish.  There's a lesson here.  When one tries to be too clever, one is sure to get something wrong.  This is why Elliott's solution is so good - it's _not_ clever.  It's very clear, easy to maintain, and it _works_.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable but I was having some fun with trying to do this with bit wise operators and I figured I would post it

```
public boolean typeMatch(char c1, char c2) {
    int xor = c1 ^ c2;
    if(xor == 6) { // 2 apart
        return c1 == '{' || c1 == '}' || c1 == '[' || c1 == ']';
    } else if(xor == 1) { // 1 apart
        return c1 == '(' || c1 == ')';
    } else if(xor == 0) { // same
        return c1 == '(' || c1 == ')' || 
                c1 == '{' || c1 == '}' || c1 == '[' || c1 == ']';
    }
    return false;
}
```

It should be quite fast at least...

Answer (score 0):

There's already an accepted answer here, and it's a good one, but it's very specific to the problem at hand.

For folks who got here by searching for a more generic solution, I'd like to offer my favorite pattern for doing away with if/else chains:

```
boolean result = false;
do {
   if(condition1) {
      result = true;
      break;
   }

   if(condition2) {
     break;
   }

   // etc.

} while(false);

return result;
```

This, of course,  is generalizable to any return type.